# How to get VM pricing information using `@ibm-cloud/platform-services`

Tags: ibm-cloud

I've been trying to get the pricing information IBM cloud VMs using `@ibm-cloud/platform-services/global-catalog/v1` ([ref](https://github.com/IBM/platform-services-node-sdk)). However I cannot find anything in the documentation on how to do that.

Documentation: https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/resource-catalog/global-catalog?code=node

Please give me an example to get the hourly pricing for the VM profile say `bx2-2x8` (VM with 2 cores and, GiB memory)